# Iterative mergesort with stacks

Tags: c, mergesort

So currently I have a mergesort function that uses a while loop to merge the array:

```
void myMergesort(void **A, int n, int(cmp)(void *, void*)) {
    Stack *s; 
    int l = 0, h = n - 1;
    stack_push(s, (void *)l);
    stack_push(s, (void *)h);
    while (!stack_isEmpty(s)) {
        h = (int)stack_pop(s);
        l = (int)stack_pop(s);
        int m = (l + h) / 2;
        if (l < m) {
            stack_push(s, (void *)l);
            stack_push(s, (void *)m);
        }
        if (m+1 < h) {
            stack_push(s, (void *)m+1);
            stack_push(s, (void *)h);
        }
        merge(A, l, m, h, cmp);
    }
}
```

Where the merge function is just the standard merge function that creates two array of A[l to m] and A[m+1 to h]

I think I am quite close to getting the mergesort to work using stack, but I am kind of stuck here as I don't know where to put my merge function. Any hints?

Comment: It would be easier if the mergesort function took another parameter, a pointer to a second temporary array for performing the merge operation. Since the array parameter is void**A, there's no way to know the size of an element and how to allocate space for a temporary array.

Comment: The size of the function is n and the assumed type is long

Comment: There's a second issue, the code calls merge with l < m and m+1 < h before it's called merge with l == m and m+1 == h., so the sequence of calls to merge appear to be out of order.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: The merge needs to start off by merging a pair of elements, in this case, when l == m and m+1 == h. Since you're using a stack and pushing the higher index last, the first merge should be two elements, array[n-2] and array[n-1]. Then another pair of elements should be merged, array[n-4] and array[n-3]. Then these two pairs should be merged at a later time, array[n-4 to n-3], array[n-2 to n-1].

Comment: Yeah that is where I am stuck do you have any hints?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73684/discussion-between-rcgldr-and-user3529361).

Comment: It would be simpler if the low index `l` was included and the high index `h` was excluded.  Such a convention is more consistent with C array indexing.  Regarding the algorithm, you could get rid of the stack completely by iterating on slices of 2^k elements, starting with k=0, merging pairs of adjacent slices in each iteration until 2^k >= n.

Comment: Comparing a top down merge sort versus a stack, what's missing with the stack approach is the current state for what to do next after popping values off the stack. For a top down sort, the possible return points are after dealing with the left half and after dealing with the right half, where a merge is performed, then a return to the previous state.

Comment: So are you saying that it isn't possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a state variable to indicate if an index range needs to be split or merged. Also I prefer to use an ending index instead of a last index (so m+1 is not needed).

```
    if(n < 2)return
    push state_split
    push n
    push 0
    while(not empty){
        pop l
        pop h
        pop state
        m = (l+h)/2
        if(state == state_split){
            if((h-l) > 1){
                push state_merge
                push h
                push l
                push state_split
                push h
                push m
                push state_split
                push m
                push l
            }
        } else {
            merge(A, l, m, h)
        }
    }
```